# как пока курсор на блоке (цели) повторять функцию?

Tags: javascript

При наведении на одну из кнопок (влево или вправо) блок скролится с шагом 1% в сторону. Пока что это происходит, когда наводишь курсор на одну из кнопок. И то, нужно 30 раз навести на кнопку, что бы получить `style="left: 30%"` и наоборот.

С чем есть 2 вопроса.

Как мне повторять без прерывно функцию, чтобы навел на кнопку и скрипт начинает прибавлять по 1% (или наоборот - убавлять);

Как запретить прибавлять по 1% в `style: left`, когда я дойду до своей цели(условия if else);

Можно ли эту затею выполнить более грамотно без готовых плагинов на чистом JS?

```
    var lf = document.querySelector('.hover-left'),
    rg = document.querySelector('.hover-right'),
    sg = document.querySelector('.slider-gallery');

var l = 0,
    r = 0;

    rg.onmouseover = function(){
        sg.style.left = l + '%';
        l--
    };

    lf.onmouseover = function(){
        sg.removeAttribute('style');
    };
```

Comment: при наведении мыши запускайте `setInterval`, в нем меняйте позицию. при выходе мыши делайте `clearInterval`

Comment: @teran Правильно, что я понимаю сделать это, как то так: rg.onmouseover = setInterval(function{ //мой код });? Просто запуск идет с загрузки страницы, или я неправильно запускаю ее?

Comment: нет, при таком вызове вы запускаете функцию, и ее результат присваиваете обработчику. Вам же надо написать функицю обработчик, внутри которой будет запускаться setInterval, который в свою очередь вернет хэндл который для дальнейшей работы надо будет сохранить.

Comment: @teran вот вот гуглил гуглил и не нагуглил. С чего начинается функция обработчик?

Comment: ну у вас же в вашем коде в вопросе навешаны обработчики. вот внутри их и запустите этот `setInterval`

Comment: @teran, а то что прибавляет каждый раз не по 1% а в геометрической прогрессии, это я так написал скрипт?Или нужны это регулировать вручную?